# Windows Store app test certificate expired

Tags: certificate, windows-store-apps

Suddenly, when running a build of my Windows Store app I got the error.

> error APPX0108: The certificate specified has expired. For more information about
>   renewing certificates, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478

There is a link to the `Renewing a certificate` page but it's just a circular reference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The information was there - just buried at the bottom of the [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/br230260(v=vs.110).aspx#renewcert):

- Open the `.appxmanifest` file in Visual Studio (app manifest designer view)
- On the **Packaging** tab in the

  - Click **Choose Certificate**
  - In the dropdown, select ***Create test certificate...***

    - This [blog post](http://www.bartlannoeye.com/blog/tfs-build-for-windows-8-app-package-the-certificate-specified-has-expired) recommends you **do not set a password**
  - Agree to replace the certificate

Comment: Before downvoting, please consider http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I cannot update the app (on existing app) after i did this. Did you experience this? Any suggestions?

Comment: but test certificate is for test? not for store right? you should probably use the option "choose from store"

Comment: Then it says: Invalid package publisher name

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new certificate:

- Open the **Package.appxmanifest**
- Select the **Packaging** tab
- Click Choose Certificate
- Click Create

  - Enter your existing publisher name
  - A password
- Agree to replace the certificate

Then you can update your microsoft store app